# Manage SharePoint Document Library using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint-2010

Ever since the SharedWorkspace object was deprecated in Excel VBA, I have been unable to find an alternative way to perform the same tasks.  Note Excel VBA is the only development tool that I have access to.  I do have SharePoint Designer, though.

Did Microsoft provide anything to replace the functionality provided by the SharedWorkspace object?

Most of my tasks involve iterating through the documents in a document library.  E.g., to see which ones were checked out, etc.  That was trivial to do using the SharedWorkspace object.  Can anyone tell me a way to do that using VBA without the SharedWorkspace object?

I've found that I can accomplish the task using the SharePoint Designer reference in my VBA code, but that requires me to open the SharePoint Designer UI, which takes too long for my needs.  (Why doesn't the SharePoint Designer Application object have a visible property like the other Office apps do?  That would have helped).

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint offers a rich set of Web services to interface with content on a site.  To iterate through all documents in a document library, you can use the [GetListItems web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx).  This will require that you write code to call the web service.  [XMLHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms759148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is one "easy" way to do so.  Please let me know if you need a code sample.